# How to order by last 3 month with left join count?

Tags: php, sql, laravel

Hi i have query to show restaurant list order by count of total order by last 3 month,

```
$resto->leftJoin('order', 'order.restaurant_id', 'restaurant.restaurant_id')
                ->groupBy('restaurant.restaurant_id')
                ->where(DB::raw("FROM_UNIXTIME(order.added)"), ">=", Carbon::now()->subMonths(3))
                ->orderBy(DB::raw("COUNT(order.order_id)"), 'DESC');
```

my code above work but, if restaurant who doesnt have order last 3 month will not show,

my expected result is show all restaurant orderBy count last 3 month, but still showing who doesnt have order last 3 month
how to do this?

Comment: What is the complete query, see by doing `$resto->toSql()`?

Comment: please show us full query and paste your code, don't put image

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are having is because you are limiting the query using the where condition, so it will always select just the once that have order in the last 3 months. I believe that the best way is to create a virtual column and then order the results by it.

So I cannot test your exact query as I don't have your codebase, but I will give you a blind try so you can try it in your codebase.

```
$resto->leftJoin('order', 'order.restaurant_id', 'restaurant.restaurant_id')
      ->groupBy('restaurant.restaurant_id')
      ->selectRaw("IF(FROM_UNIXTIME(order.added) >= ?) as latest_orders_count"), [Carbon::now()->subMonths(3)->timestamp])
      ->orderBy(DB::raw("COUNT(order.order_id)"), 'DESC') // first order by count
      ->orderBy('latest_orders_count', 'DESC'); // then by latest
```

Comment: i try your code and trow error
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'latest_orders_count' in 'order clause'

Comment: @RIFAL and what do you get without the last `orderBy`?

Comment: that error because i already has select, so i move that select() into selectRow() and error became like this
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '08:58:01) AS latest_orders_count) from `restaurant` left join `order` on `order`' at line 1 (SQL: select distinct restaurant.*, COUNT(FROM_UNIXTIME(order.added) >= 2019-02-09 08:58:01) AS latest_orders_count)

Comment: Okay, can you please try the exact query I gave you above, so just copy and replace yours to make sure you are still not missing something else?

Comment: I believe that my edit now will fix it. You should pass the timestamp, like this:
`Carbon::now()->subMonths(3)->timestamp`

Comment: i copy ur code and got this error, SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ') as latest_orders_count) from `restaurant` left join `order` on `order`.`restau'

Comment: thanks for your answers, its work now, i modify the code, but the points is, you answer is correct.